# Prawn: Different margin on odd and even pages destroyed by column_box

Tags: ruby, margin, prawn

I created pages with different margin for odd and even pages (more space on the inner side) for the punch holes.

```
require 'prawn'
require "prawn/measurement_extensions"
require 'forgery'

MARGIN_ODD  = [10.mm, 10.mm, 10.mm, 30.mm] #right page
MARGIN_EVEN = [10.mm, 30.mm, 10.mm, 10.mm] #left page
PAGE_SIZE   = 'A4'
PAGE_LAYOUT = :portrait

class MyPrawnDocument < Prawn::Document
  def start_new_page(options={})
    # page_number before start_new_page is called
    page_number.odd? ? super({margin: MARGIN_EVEN}.merge(options)) : super({margin: MARGIN_ODD}.merge(options))
  end
end

MyPrawnDocument.generate("listing.pdf", margin: MARGIN_ODD) do
  100.times do
    text Forgery(:lorem_ipsum).words(7)
  end 
end
```

Now i want to formart the text into 2 columns per page.
I used `column_box` as documented.

```
MyPrawnDocument.generate("listing.pdf", margin: MARGIN_ODD) do
  column_box( [0,cursor], columns: 2, width: bounds.width ) do
    100.times do
      text Forgery(:lorem_ipsum).words(7)
    end 
  end
end
```

Now i have the text in 2 columns but the toggling margin is missing.

Any idea how i can have 2 columns **and** different margin on odd and even pages?